# How can I add a description of the deprecated list?

Tags: documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

I was able to add custom pages to the doxygen documentation even with a description (which is not realy documentated). However I have this here:

```
/*!
 * \page fielname Here comes the title
 * \brief A short introduction which explains this page.
 *
 * The real page content...
 */
```

That works fine but how I add a `\brief` (description) for the deprecated list? Now that looks a undocumentated page what I want to avoid.

Comment: Can I just confirm that you want to add an introduction to the page _automatically generated_ by Doxygen from the `\deprecated` tags?

Comment: @Cheeseminer that would be cool too, but no I want on the generated `pages.html` add a description for e.g. the *deprecated list* and all other lists like the todo list and other `\xrefitem` lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for can be achieved with the following:

```
/** Test class
 *  @deprecated Will be removed in release 2.0
 */
class Test
{
};

/** @page deprecated
 *  @brief Deprecated page brief
 *
 *  Deprecated page contents.
 */
```

Comment: That is great thank you! Some small off topic where should I report one bug? I have a class with generics which contains a nested static class even with generics is not documentated with doxygen.

Comment: The doxygen site has a link to the bugzilla database it uses for bug reports.  See http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/trouble.html#bug_reports